# How to run script when user login using sftp

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, data-recovery, rescue

Here I need to run one of the script when login user using sftp, because something misconfigured `sshd-config` file so that `SSH` login not working but sftp working fine, My plan is to replace `sshd-config` file using sftp.

Note: Root user also going into the jail means only home directory showing when user login.
Is it possible to do that or any other way ?

Comment: Yes. It should work with sftp as user root.

Comment: @MichaelD. I've root user credential and able to login with sftp, Can you please tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Root user also going into the jail means only home directory showing when user login. Is it possible to do that or any other way ?

If the `root` is chrooted you can not access files outside of home directory. Even if you could, you can not restart `sshd` server over `sftp` to apply the new configuration.

Comment: First I like to change configuration then will do the restart the server to restart the service.